# Full-Width E-mail Template?

Tags: android, html, css, ios, email

I recently received an e-mail that appears full-width on IOS G-Mail App:

https://ibb.co/FBd03XH

When trying to recreate, it always looks like this:

https://ibb.co/kMY0FLm

Edit: Added code

```
<div role="article" style="background-color:#000">
    <table role="presentation" style="width:100%;border:none;border-spacing:0">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="padding:0">
  <table role="presentation" style="width:94%;max-width:600px;border:none;border-spacing:0;text-align:left;font-family:system-ui;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;color:#fff">
            <tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h1 style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:16px;font-size:26px;line-height:32px;font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:-0.02em">Welcome to our responsive email!</h1>
                <p style="margin:0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, <a href="http://www.example.com/" style="color:#e50d70;text-decoration:underline">eget accumsan dictum</a>, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat.</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:0;font-size:24px;line-height:28px;font-weight:bold">
                <a href="http://www.example.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/210284/1200x800-2.png" width="600" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#363636"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:35px 30px 11px 30px;font-size:0;background-color:#ffffff;border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f5">
  
  
                <div class="col-sml" style="width:100%;max-width:145px;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;font-family:system-ui;font-size:14px;color:#363636">
                  <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/210284/icon.png" width="115" alt="" style="width:115px;max-width:80%;margin-bottom:20px">
                </div>


                <div class="col-lge" style="width:100%;max-width:395px;vertical-align:top;padding-bottom:20px;font-family:system-ui;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;color:#363636">
                  <p style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:12px">Nullam mollis sapien vel cursus fermentum. Integer porttitor augue id ligula facilisis pharetra. In eu ex et elit ultricies ornare nec ac ex. Mauris sapien massa, placerat non venenatis et, tincidunt eget leo.</p>
                  <p style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:18px">Nam non ante risus. Vestibulum vitae eleifend nisl, quis vehicula justo. Integer viverra efficitur pharetra. Nullam eget erat nibh.</p>
                  <p style="margin:0"><a href="https://example.com/" style="background: #ff3884;text-decoration: none;padding: 10px 25px;color: #ffffff;border-radius: 4px"><span style="font-weight:bold">Claim yours now</span></a></p>
                </div>
   
   
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:30px;font-size:24px;line-height:28px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#ffffff;border-bottom:1px solid #f0f0f5">
                <a href="http://www.example.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/210284/1200x800-1.png" width="540" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#363636"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:30px;background-color:#ffffff">
                <p style="margin:0">Duis sit amet accumsan nibh, varius tincidunt lectus. Quisque commodo, nulla ac feugiat cursus, arcu orci condimentum tellus, vel placerat libero sapien et libero. Suspendisse auctor vel orci nec finibus.</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:30px;text-align:center;font-size:12px;background-color:#404040;color:#cccccc">
                <p style="margin:0 0 8px 0"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/210284/facebook_1.png" width="40" height="40" alt="f" style="color:#cccccc"></a> <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/210284/twitter_1.png" width="40" height="40" alt="t" style="color:#cccccc"></a></p>
                <p style="margin:0;font-size:14px;line-height:20px">&reg; Someone, Somewhere 2021<br><a class="unsub" href="http://www.example.com/" style="color:#cccccc;text-decoration:underline">Unsubscribe instantly</a></p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Post your code or we can't help you

Comment: @BernardBorg Sorry

Comment: Don't post external links, they could die and then this question would be worthless to the posterity

Comment: You have width: 94% on your table. What happens when you remove that?

Comment: Gmail has dedicated heuristics to make emails full width or not. You can see a thread with different solutions you can explore here: https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/57